# Prove this exp and log inequality?

Tags: inequality

show that
$$e^x-\ln{(x+2)}>\dfrac{1}{6}\tag{(1)}$$

I know
$$e^x>x+1,\ln{(x+2)}<x+1$$
so I have only prove
$$e^x-\ln{(x+2)}>0$$
But How to prove $(1)$?

Comment: What is $x+1,ln(x+2)$? Second inequality not making sense $A>B<C$?

Comment: @Benedict it is two separate inequalities separated by a comma. They boy make sense

Comment: In what context did you see this inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A look at the graphs of $y=e^x$ and $y=\log(x+2)$ shows  that the line $y=1+x$ is a tangent to both of them, and that it suffices to prove the inequality in question for the interval $-1<x<0$.

We start with the inequalities 
$$e^{-t}>1-t+{t^2\over2}-{t^3\over 6},\qquad\log(1+t)<t-{t^2\over2}+{t^3\over3}\qquad(0<t<1)$$
resulting from truncating alternating series. This implies
$$e^x>1+x+{x^2\over 2}+{x^3\over6}\qquad(-1<x<0)\tag{1}$$
and
$$\log(x+2)=\log\bigl(1+(x+1)\bigr)<(1+x)-{(1+x)^2\over2}+{(1+x)^3\over3}\qquad(-1<x<0)\ .\tag{2}$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we obtain by subtraction
$$\eqalign{e^x-\log(x+2)&>1+x+{x^2\over 2}+{x^3\over6}-\left({5\over6}+x+{x^2\over2}+{x^3\over3}\right)\cr &={1\over6}(1-x^3)>{1\over6}\qquad(-1<x<0)\ . \cr} $$

Answer (score 0):

What I wrote previously is wrong.

As Dr. MV points out in his comment,

> $e^x−\log(x+2)$  is not monotonically increasing on (−2,∞). There is an
>   absolute minimum when $e^x$=$1\over x+2$, which occurs at x≈−0.442854227254517
>   where f(x)≈0.199346303057501.

Note that this value is strictly greater than $\frac{1}{6}$, which proves the inequality (since the minimum value is greater than $\frac{1}{6}$ for all $x$ in (−2,∞).

**Previous, wrong answer**

<strike>Claim: if the inequality holds at x=0, it will also hold for all x greater than 0.</strike>

Sketch of proof: both $e^x$ and $\ln(x+2)$ are monotone increasing functions; the derivative of $e^x$ is always greater, so as $x$ increases, $e^x - \ln(x+2)$ can only increase.

At $x=0$, we have $1 - \ln(2) > \frac{1}{6}$ by direct evaluation.

For $x \le -1$ we have no problem because then $\ln(x+2)$ is either negative or undefined whereas $e^x$ is always positive.

For $-1<x<0$, we have a similar argument as for $x=0$; at $x=-1$, we have $e^{-1} - 0 > \frac{1}{6}$, so for all $x$ greater the inequality will continue to hold for the same reason as given above.

In fact the case $x \ge0$ probably can be folded into this one.

As for the motivation for the inequality or for a more elegant proof (probably using Taylor series), I unfortunately don't know the answer.

Comment: I think this proof is technically correct, but it is not very enlightening, so I encourage someone with a better answer to post -- I just didn't want to leave OP with nothing.

Comment: $e^x-\log(x+2)$ is not monotonically increasing on $(-2,\infty)$.  There is an absolute minimum when $e^x=\frac{1}{x+2}$, which occurs at $x \approx -0.442854227254517$ where $f(x) \approx 0.199346303057501
$

Comment: That makes sense; I figured there was something wrong with the "proof" given how uninspired it was.

Answer (score 0):

I have slove this problem

Let $$f(x)=e^x-\ln{(x+2)}-\dfrac{1}{6}\Longrightarrow f'(x)=e^x-\dfrac{1}{x+2},f''(x)=e^x+\dfrac{1}{x+2}>0$$
Note $f'(1)>0,f'(-1)<0$,so $f'(x)=0$ has unieque real solution $x_{0}$,
so we have
$$f(x)\ge f(x_{0})=e^{x_{0}}-\ln{(x_{0}+2)}-\dfrac{1}{6}$$
Let $$f'(x_{0})=e^{x_{0}}-\dfrac{1}{x_{0}+2}=0\Longrightarrow \ln{(x_{0}+2)}+x_{0}=0$$
so we have
$$f(x_{0})=e^{x_{0}}+x_{0}-\dfrac{1}{6}=\dfrac{1}{x_{0}+2}+x_{0}-\dfrac{1}{6}$$
sine$\ln{(x_{0}+2)}+x_{0}=0$,Let $g(x)=\ln{(x+2)}+x\Longrightarrow g(-0.5)=\ln{1.5}-0.5<o.5-0.5<0, g(1)>0$,so we have $x_{0}>-0.5$
so we have $t=x_{0}+2>1.5$
$$f(x)\ge x_{0}+\dfrac{1}{x_{0}+2}-\dfrac{1}{6}=t+\dfrac{1}{t}-\dfrac{13}{6}>1.5+\dfrac{2}{3}-\dfrac{13}{6}=0$$